# JQuery ajax post function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wanted to create a form that submits data to my php script and posts this data back to my page.
 This is my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX POST</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[name="submit"]").click(function(){
                    var username=$("input[name="username"]").attr("value");
                    var password=$("input[name="password"]").attr("value");
                    var data1=encodeURIComponent(username);
                    var data2=encodeURIComponent(password);
                    $.post("response.php",data1+"&"+data2,function(data){
                        $("#form").hide();
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form action="response.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br/>
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my server side script named response.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["username"]."<br/>";
    echo $_POST["password"];
?>
```

I am unable to get the expected result.Please help!

Comment: a lot of problems in this code , use console and look at jquery.post documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
.post("response.php",data1+"&"+data2,function(data){
```

Should be:

```
$.post("response.php",data1+"&"+data2,function(data){
```

Answer (score 4):

Send your data over in a key/val pair:

```
$.post("response.php", {username: data1, password: data2} ,function(data){
    $("#form").hide();
    $("#response").html(data);
});
```

Better not be storing passwords in plain text either... :D

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax errors that you should have spotted yourself [using the console of your browser](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

For example change

```
$("input[name="submit"]").click(function(){
```

to

```
$('input[name="submit"]').click(function(){
```

An editor with syntax highlighting would be helpful too, as you may have noticed here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are missing `$` on your following call:

```
$.post("response.php",data1+"&"+data2,function(data){

$("#form").hide();
$("#response").html(data);

});
```